# transid should be unique store in laravel check (value transid should be single store)

Tags: php, laravel

I am confused how to store unique value in laravel i would like to store only single value transaction_id there should not be more than one value there. please suggest.

```
            $payment                     = new Payment;
            $payment->order_id           = Input::get('orderid');
            $payment->amount             = (Input::get('base_amount', 0))?Input::get('base_amount'):Input::get('amount');
            $payment->transaction_id     = Input::get('transact');

            how to check if this $payment->transaction_id already exists should not save more than one

            i tried 

            $payment = Payment::where('transaction_id', '=', Input::get('transaction_id'))->first();
            if ($payment === null) {
               $payment->save();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Request validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'transaction_id' => 'unique'
    ];
}
```

If you use this method, you should create new Request class with `php artisan make:request MyRequest` command. Then put `rules()` in the created `MyRequest` and then you can just use it iside your store/update actions (functions) inside your RESTful controller:

```
public function store(MyRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation

Also, you can use validation in your Model:

```
private $rules = [
    'transaction_id' => 'required'
    ];
```

Comment: okay where to put this? I mean in my model one more question will it produce single transaction entry i mean it should save one transaction_id not more than does this work?

Comment: where do i use public function rules()
{
    return [
        'transaction_id' => 'unique'
    ];
} @Alexey

Comment: You should put it in your request class, please look at my post. It works in Laravel 5, but I'm not sure if this feature available in 4.2.